# Explicit formula for $e_k = 4e_{k-1} + 5$

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, recursion

The sequence looks like this:

$e_0 = 2$

$e_1 = 4(e_{1-1}) + 5 = 13$

$e_2 = 4(e_{2-1}) + 5 = 57$

$e_3 = 4(e_{3-1}) + 5 = 233$

$e_4 = 4(e_{4-1}) + 5 = 937$

How would I go about finding the explicit formula for this?  For something a little simpler it's fairly easy to make a guess, and I've been told that 'guessing' is exactly how one is supposed to find the formula.  However, I'm a little stumped on this.

Comment: Let $x_k=e_k+\frac53$, can you express $x_k$ in terms of $x_{k-1}$? Hence?

Comment: A systematic method that is useful for linear recurrences (and sometimes not linear ones) is solving through generating functions. You can see some examples [here](https://www.math.cmu.edu/~af1p/Teaching/Combinatorics/Slides/Generating-Functions.pdf).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A general approach to deal with recurring sequences of the form $$u_{n+1} = au_n +b$$

- if $a = 1$, it's an [arithmetic progression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression).
- otherwise, let $r=\frac{b}{1-a}$. Consider $v_n = u_n -r$. we have
  $$
  v_{n+1} = u_{n+1} - r = au_n+b - r = a(v_n + r) + b - r = a v_n
  $$
  and $(v_n)_n$ is a [geometric progression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression). You can then get the closed form for $v_n$, and $u_n = v_n + r$ will give you that of $u_n$.

Comment: I'm very confused on the variables $u, v, r$, you've introduced here.

Comment: $(u_n)$ is a sequence you're given: I've used the letter $u$, but when applying it to your case "your $u_n$ will be $e_n$," with $a=4$ and $b=5$. $(v_n)_n$ is a new sequence you can define based on $(u_n)_n$, as a "proxy" to find the closed-form expression of $u_n$ (studying $v_n$ is easier than directly studying $u_n$, since it'll have a simpler behavior). $r$ is a parameter (in your case, $r=\frac{5}{4-1} = \frac{5}{3}$) that will help in doing so.

Comment: Sorry, here $r = \frac{b}{1-a} = \frac{5}{1-4} = -\frac{5}{3}$ (there is a typo in the above comment, the minus sign is missing).

Answer (score 1):

Let $e_n=4^nu_n$, then 
$$
4^{n}u_{n}=e_{n}=4e_{n-1}+5=4\cdot 4^{n-1}u_{n-1}+5=4^{n}u_{n-1}+5
$$
and thus
$$
u_{n}=u_{n-1}+\frac{5}{4^{n}}=\left(u_{n-2}+\frac{5}{4^{n-1}}\right)+\frac{5}{4^{n}}=\cdots=u_0+\frac{5}{4}+\frac{5}{4^2}+\cdots+\frac{5}{4^{n}} \\
=u_0+\frac{5}{4}\left(1+\frac{1}{4}+\cdots+\frac{1}{4^{n-1}}\right)=u_0+\frac{5}{4}\left(\frac{1-\frac{1}{4^{n}}}{1-\frac{1}{4}}\right)=u_0+\frac{5}{3}\left(1-\frac{1}{4^n}\right)
$$
and as $u_0=2$,
$$
e_n=4^nu_{n}=2+\frac{5}{3}( 4^n-1)
$$

Comment: Also $u_0=2$ has to be multiplied by $4^n$, The right answer is $e_n=\frac{11}{3}4^n-\frac{5}{3}$

Answer (score 0):

$e_0 = 2$
$e_1 = 4e_0 + 5$
$e_2 = 4e_1 + 5=4^2e_0 + 4(5) + 5$
$e_3 = 4e_2 + 5=4^3e_0 + 4^2(5)+ 4^1(5) + 5= 4^3e_0+5(1 + 4^1 + 4^2 + 4^3)$

Now you should be able to guess that:

$e_k = 4^ke_0+5(1 + 4^1 + 4^2 + 4^3+...+4^{k-1})=4^ke_0 + \frac{5(4^k-1)}{3}$

and then you can prove that your "guess" is correct using induction.